# Angular 2 - append withCredentials = true with every http request

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-providers

I am using angular 2 (not latest as using through angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.9-4) and I have to set withCredentials to true for every http request. I tried to set it up for one request using

http.get('http://my.domain.com/request', { withCredentials: true })

and everything is working fine however I am trying to use something in bootstrap as below but not getting any success

```
import './polyfills.ts';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app/';
import {Http, Headers, BaseRequestOptions, RequestOptions, BrowserXhr} from '@angular/http';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

export class MyRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.headers.append('withCredentials','true');
  }
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, 
  [{ provide: RequestOptions, useClass: MyRequestOptions}]
);
```

Comment: Hi,
I'm facing the same problem, did you figured out how to do this?

Comment: No I haven't resolved it yet...

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is required anymore, but I had the same problem and I've solved in this way:

1. Create a subclass of BaseRequestOptions (which extends RequestOptions):

   ```
   import { Headers, BaseRequestOptions } from "@angular/http";

   export class AuthRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
      constructor() {
         super();
         this.withCredentials = true;
      }
   }
   ```
2. Register it in application bootstrap

   ```
   import { RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
   import { AuthRequestOptions } from './<path>/AuthRequestOptions';

   @NgModule({
      bootstrap: [...],
      imports: [...],
      providers: [
         { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: AuthRequestOptions},
         ...
      ]
   }...
   ```

(In my case, this is that worked with CORS+NTLMAuthentication)

Comment: In case you are using Angular 4.3+ with HttpClientModule, refer to this article: https://spikesapps.wordpress.com/2017/08/04/how-to-implement-windows-authentication-in-an-angular-4-3-1-application-with-a-stand-alone-web-api/

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by `Sierrodc` Angular 4.3+ allows interceptors usage to configure this. A full example that works with NTLMAuthentication is shown below:

**The interceptor**

```
@Injectable()
export class WithCredentialsInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {


    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        request = request.clone({
            withCredentials: true
        });

        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

**Module configuration** (the interceptor allows stacking with other interceptors):

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, BasicRoutingModule, HttpClientModule],
    declarations: [HomeComponent, CounterComponent, FetchDataComponent],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: WithCredentialsInterceptor,
            multi: true
        },
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: BaseUrlInterceptor,
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class BasicModule { }
```

**Actual usage**

```
constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) {

    this.http.get<WeatherForecast[]>('api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts')
        .subscribe(result => {
            this.forecasts = result;
        },
        error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}
```